# Lifetime issues: return struct containing reference to local closure

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde

I am attempting to model some program state as `Mutables` from the [`futures-signals` library](https://docs.rs/futures-signals/), whose value I want to set generically from a [serde_json `Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) identified by some string key.

For example, given I received some payload instructing me to update `"my_int"` with a `Value`, I want to be able to set the value of the `Mutable` that is known as `"my_int"`.

My idea was to have a map from identifiers like `"my_int"` to a **non-templated** wrapper around a mutable's setter. It is important that said wrapper is non-templated, because otherwise I couldn't hold a collection of them in one map:

```rust
let my_int = Mutable::new(123);
let my_str = Mutable::new("asdf");
// ...

let setters = HashMap::from([
    ("my_int", /* magic wrapper around setter here somehow */),
    ("my_str", /* magic wrapper around setter here somehow */),
    // ...
]);

let property_name = "my_int"; // constant for demo purposes
let value = Value::from(234); // constant for demo purposes
let setter = setters.get(property_name).unwrap();
(setter.deser_and_set)(value);
```

Right now said magic wrapper looks like this:

```rust
struct SetterWrapper<'a> {
    name: &'static str,
    deser_and_set: &'a dyn Fn(Value) -> Result<(), Error>,
    // + some other unrelated fields
}
```

And I can create those **inline**, and it **works**:

```rust
let my_int_setter = SetterWrapper {
    name: "my_int",
    deser_and_set: &(|v: Value| {
        my_int.set(serde_json::from_value(v)?);
        Ok(())
    }),
    // + some other unrelated fields
};
```

But I have many mutables and don't want to repeat the above code for every one of them, so I attempted to put it into a function:

```rust
fn wrap_setter<'a, T>(name: &'static str, mutable: &'a Mutable<T>) -> SetterWrapper<'a>
    where T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de>
{
    let deser_and_set = |v: Value| {
        mutable.set(serde_json::from_value::<T>(v)?);
        Ok(())
    };
    SetterWrapper {
        name,
        deser_and_set: &deser_and_set,
    }
}
```

which I intend to use like `let my_int_setter = wrap_setter("my_int", &my_int);`, however I am encountering the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `deser_and_set`
  --> src\main.rs:66:5
   |
66 | /     SetterWrapper {
67 | |         name,
68 | |         deser_and_set: &deser_and_set,
   | |                        -------------- `deser_and_set` is borrowed here
69 | |     }
   | |_____^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The error itself makes sense to me: of course I can't return references to local variables, as those would dangle. But I believe conceptually I could solve the issue by somehow marking the closure in the function to have the same lifetime as the mutable, namely `'a`, but you cannot give variables lifetime annotations.

How can I solve this issue? Or is my approach already clumsy?

Comment: You could put a `Box<dyn Fn(Value) -> Result<(), Error>>` in your `SetterWrapper` instead of a reference. Or define `wrap_setter` as a macro instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

To work around the issue, one way I can think of is change the property `deser_and_set` to a `Box` from a reference. With that, the ownership of the Box can be moved out of the function. Give it a try.

```
struct SetterWrapper {
    name: &'static str,
    deser_and_set: Box<dyn Fn(Value) -> Result<(), Error>>,
    // + some other unrelated fields
}

fn wrap_setter<T>(name: &'static str, mutable: &Mutable<T>) -> SetterWrapper
    where T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de>
{
    SetterWrapper {
        name,
        deser_and_set: Box::new(|v: Value| {
            mutable.set(serde_json::from_value::<T>(v)?);
            Ok(())
        };),
    }
}
```

Comment: That certainly looks promising, but I'm getting follow-up lifetime-related errors: `the parameter type `T` may not live long enough`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer from @Joe_Jingyu is cleaner but I want to point out a second way you could take:

make `SetterWrapper` a trait and implement it for `Mutable`:

```rust
trait SetterWrapper {
    fn deser_and_set(&self, v: Value) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

impl<T> SetterWrapper for Mutable<T>
where
    T: for<'de> serde::de::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deser_and_set(&self, v: Value) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.set(serde_json::from_value::<T>(v)?);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now you can create the HashMap with the trait objects and set the value:

```rust
let setters = HashMap::from([
    ("my_int", &my_int as &dyn SetterWrapper),
    ("my_str", &my_str),
]);

let property_name = "my_int"; // constant for demo purposes
let value = Value::from(234); // constant for demo purposes
let setter = setters.get(property_name).unwrap();
// now the call can be direct
setter.deser_and_set(value).unwrap();
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccd232d9f77b76ce2d055fdf4a55f51b) (Note: I have build a simple Mutable myself, just to make the example work)

Comment: That seems to work nicely, thank you! Can you elaborate why you'd consider this to be a less clean solution? It certainly feels elegant to me when I name the trait something like `SetFromJsonValue`

Comment: In your `SetterWrapper` you had another field (`name`). Trait objects can't do that. Keep in mind that Trait objects have some limitations (which bothered me a couple of times). And also dynamic dispatch adds a slight runtime cost. But if you are fine with that they are really nice